# Cannot read input from input filehandle

Tags: perl

I am having an issue with Perl and handling an input file.

I am opening the file successfully; however, when I try to print the contents of the file to screen, it doesn't print anything.

If I perform a system call to cat on that file name before I try to print to screen the print to screen works?!

*Not Working*

```
open( my $ifh, "<", "$stream->{ fname }.SortIndex.dat" )
    or die "$product: $stream->{ fname }.SortIndex.dat could not open parm file file.dat: $!";

while ( <$ifh> ) {
    print $_;
}
```

*Working*

```
open( my $ifh, "<", "$stream->{ fname }.SortIndex.dat" )
    or die "$product: $file could not open parm $stream->{ fname }.SortIndex.dat: $!";

system ( "cat $stream->{ fname }.SortIndex.dat" );

while ( <$ifh> ) {
    print $_;
}
```

It's got me stumped, I have tried throwing the handle into an array and printing the elements of the array without success.

The file handle opens without error, it only contains one line and it is a Unix-formatted text file.

Has anyone seen this sort of behavior before?

*I am also performing cat on the same file now:*

```
system( "cat $stream->{ fname }.SortIndex.dat" );
```

Previous behavior persists.

Comment: Can you `print "$stream->{ fname }.SortIndex.dat\n"` and add the output of that into your question?

Comment: Sure thing, See edit ^^

Comment: cat was included for testing only and the perl script was run in the /data/$client/$product/ directory. I can perform another test with cat  using the same path if you like.

Comment: I think @toolic is on the right track. In your "working" version, is the file printed twice?

Comment: How do you know what you see in your file isn't being produced by the `cat`?

Comment: I suppose I don't know that, however what could cat produce ? Wouldn't cat just show what is in the file.

Comment: David W set me on the right path. I wasn't closing my SortIndex.dat files prior to running the routine that opens them for the next stage of processing. I can only imagine calling the cat via system( ) was flushing the buffer and writing the file out. Sorry for wasting your time, Its been a really long week .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David W set me on the right path.

I wasn't closing my SortIndex.dat files prior to running the routine that opens them for the next stage of processing.

I can only imagine calling the cat via system( ) was flushing the buffer and writing the file out.

Sorry for wasting your time, Its been a really long week .......

Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: You are also able to turn off filehandle buffering. However, you might also like to pipe the output to another command instead of creating an intermediate file.